# bigtable springroo

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-roo

i looked through the expense example, but it doesn't show how to use google'KEY' as primary key. **Any example of open source project that using springroo to generate complex bigtable schemas**? would be good reference for newcomer, on **de-normalized table structure**..etc .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring roo for gae does not support references till the current milestone 1.1.0M1. So, you can not generate complex schemas with spring roo for gae currently. Spring-roo is very naive for gae applications you have to wait sometime. SpringRoo official release in october so wait for that. It will be a RAD for java developers